# BizTalk getting "invalid token" when try to run Orchestration with the expression below

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-orchestrations

I have a task that involves using an Orchestration to de-batch a multi-record XML file and then sort it based on one field's value. The first expression outside the loop gets the record count:

```
recordCount = System.Convert.ToInt32(xpath(CustFile,("count/*[local-name()='Root' and namespace-uri()='']/*[local-name()='People' and namespace-uri()='']/*[local-name()='Customer' and namespace-uri()='']")));

counter = 0;

recordNumber = 0;
```

Next Expression inside the loop sets the Xpath value:

```
sXPath = System.String.Format("/*[local-name()='Root' and namespace-uri()='']/*[local-name()='People' and namespace-uri()='']/*[local-name()='Customer' and namespace-uri()='']", recordNumber);
```

The Next Expression defines the final message:

```
InternalCust = xpath(CustFile,sXPath);
```

The final expression increments the record counter for the loop to back and start again with the next record:

```
counter = counter + 1;
```

I think I can manage the sorting of the output message, but when I try to run it as is I get the following error in the console:

> xlang/s engine event log entry: Uncaught exception (see the 'inner exception' below) has suspended an instance of service 'BizTalk_SelfStudy_Week_4_Project.BizTalk_Orchestration1(ae65e0c4-9db7-6f19-1e08-6f4fbe08affe)'.
>   The service instance will remain suspended until administratively resumed or terminated. 
>   If resumed the instance will continue from its last persisted state and may re-throw the same unexpected exception.
>
> InstanceId: 4a2d7256-4882-4853-8f7c-6e6054e78c4c
>
> Shape name: Debatch Message
>
> ShapeId: 6ee14c8d-e55b-408b-be63-e5d83fa412a6
>
> Exception thrown from: segment 1, progress 19
>
> Inner exception: The part 'part' of message 'InternalCust' contained a null value at the end of the construct block.
>
> Exception type: NullPartException
>   Source: Microsoft.XLANGs.Engine
>   Target Site: Void ConstructionCompleteEvent(Boolean)
>   The following is a stack trace that identifies the location where the exception occured
>
> at Microsoft.XLANGs.Core.Part.ConstructionCompleteEvent(Boolean fKillUnderlyingPart)
>      at Microsoft.XLANGs.Core.XMessage.ConstructionCompleteEvent(Boolean killUnderlyingPartWhenDirty)
>      at BizTalk_SelfStudy_Week_4_Project.BizTalk_Orchestration1.segment1(StopConditions stopOn)
>      at Microsoft.XLANGs.Core.SegmentScheduler.RunASegment(Segment s, StopConditions stopCond, Exception& exp)

I am at a loss, as I've tried to validate the xpath and all I get is the invalid token message on the validator. Ideas anyone?

Comment: Can you add the names of the shapes?  The one where it is failing is "Debatch Message".   Set a breakpoint in the Orchestration and step through and look at the variables.  Use Dan Sharps XML viewer to test the XPath being generated https://dansharpxmlviewer.codeplex.com/

Comment: Note, the Format() has no effect since the replacement token is missing.

Comment: Q: Why can't you debatch with the XmlDisassembler?

Comment: The XmlDisassembler was used in the port exercise--the goal is to use the orchestration for everything this go around.

Comment: As Johns noted. your Format statement is wrong as it does not have a place holder for the recordNumber in the string, so your XPath statement will be wrong, so it won't work.  Please learn how to Debug an Orchestration https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa577988.aspx

Comment: Dijkgraaf thanks for the link (https://dansharpxmlviewer.codeplex.com/)--but I can't use it as the only machine I have is work (laptop) and the Dev server both of which they are a bit sticky about installing stuff onto--wont happen on server, maybe on laptop once I confirm with IT it is okay. THese are among my limitations...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Johns-305 has pointed out, your construction of the XPath is wrong

```
sXPath = System.String.Format("/*[local-name()='Root' and namespace-uri()='']/*[local-name()='People' and namespace-uri()='']/*[local-name()='Customer' and namespace-uri()='']", recordNumber);
```

It is missing a placeholder e.g. '{0}' which it would substitute the recordNumber into.

It probably should look like the below, which tells it which instance of Customer to select.

```
sXPath = System.String.Format("/*[local-name()='Root' and namespace-uri()='']/*[local-name()='People' and namespace-uri()='']/*[local-name()='Customer' and namespace-uri()=''][{0}]", recordNumber);
```

It also helps to [Debug an Orchestration](http://Debugging%20an%20Orchestration) which would have allowed you to see that the XPath didn't include the Record Number and to test the Xpaths produced, a tool useful for this is [Dan Sharps XML Viewer](https://dansharpxmlviewer.codeplex.com/)